# How to generate ASP.NET page every time when using master pages?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I'm moving an old VBScript web site over to ASP.NET, so I'm starting to use master pages instead of #includeing lots of other files with server side VBScript in them.

How can I stop the pages (as in the ones that are based on master pages) from being generated once and then stored? If I make a change to the master page (or any page based on them) those changes are not visible, because the web server is still giving out the previous versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have [caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx) enabled, as normal behaviour without caching is to regenrate.

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be the case, are you sure it's not a caching issue?